# Pass value in 3 dropdown in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I need to make a crawler for a tyres website. For that, I need to extract all the dimensions and then pass this dimension in 3 dropdown, click on the search button and extract brand name and price for each product. Then go back to the next set of dimension and..repeat until all the dimensions are finished.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tyreWidth.size(); i++) {
            String option1 = tyreWidth.get(i).getText();
            dropdownWidth.selectByIndex(i);
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            tyreSections = dropdownSection.getOptions();
            for (int j = 0; j < tyreSections.size(); j++) {
                String option2 = tyreSections.get(j).getText();
                dropdownSection.selectByIndex(j);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                tyreDiameter = dropdownDiameter.getOptions();

                for (int k = 0; k < tyreDiameter.size(); k++) {
                    dropdownDiameter.selectByIndex(k);
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                                ".//*[@id='content-groesse']/div[3]/span[2]/button"))
                                .click();// search button
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                                ".//*[@id='bottomArticleCount']/ul/li[3]/button"))
                                .click();// search all oferts
                        driver.navigate().back();
                        driver.navigate().back();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        listDimensions.add(option1 + " " + option2 + " "
                                + tyreDiameter.get(k).getText());
                        System.out.println(option1 + " " + option2 + " "
                                + tyreDiameter.get(k).getText());
                    }

                        tyreDiameter.removeAll(tyreDiameter);
                            }
            tyreSections.removeAll(tyreSections);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listDimensions.size(); i++) {
            writer.println(listDimensions.get(i));

        }
        writer.close();

    }
```

Problem: this works only for the first set of dimension. Any sugestions, please? Thanks.

Comment: Two questions; 1) When you say "_only works for the first set_", do you mean one iteration, or do you mean that something errors out after the first run? 2) Can you confirm that `tyreWidth.size() > 1`? Without the HTML and how you are locating the elements there is a lot of black box.

Comment: After the first run, values from dropdown change with original values. Values when you open the page are (205,55,R16). So, after the first iteration , the next set of values are the original one.(website: www.reifen.com). 
I'm a beginner, I hope I was clear in the explanations

Answer (score 1):

The code for the most part looks fine. I'm going to assume that somewhere higher up is a line similar to:

```
List<WebElement> tyreWidth = dropdownWidth.getOptions();
```

Otherwise the initial loop will fail and the whole thing is moot.

The only other suggestion I have is that since the dropdowns are dynamically filling (or at least that's the impression you are giving), the javascript that fills in Selection and Diameter are not being triggered correctly so you always get the defaults. See if this timeline matches up with what you're seeing:

- `dropdownWidth.selectByIndex(i);`
- This sets the width dropdown but since it still has focus, nothing changes
- `dropdownSection.selectByIndex(j);`
- This sets the section dropdown, causing the width dropdown to lose focus and get triggered
- Width is now considered set, so it dynamically recreates the list for Section and defaulting to the first option
- `dropdownDiameter.selectByIndex(k);`
- This sets the Diameter to the first option
- click(), click() and start over

So every time you set the Section, it resets the Width which resets the Section and Diameter is always the default

Try stepping through your code and see if this is the case. If it is, you just need to do something to click out of the dropdown after it is set.

```
public void clickOut() {
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
}
```

Add `clickOut();` after each `.selectByIndex()` statement and before the `sleep()`. This will cause the dropdown to lose focus and hopefully cause the  secondary and tertiary dropdowns to fill properly.